# How to access elements in listagg in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

For example, if I use listagg and get output as -

| Customer_id | Listagg |
| --- | --- |
| A | (4, 6, 8, 9, 10) |
| B | (3, 4, 6, 8, 1) |
| C | (1, 2, 4, 6, 9) |
| D | (2, 9, 10) |

If I want to print/select those rows which have 4 and 9, both in them (i.e., A and C in this case), how would I do it?

Comment: The right way would be to select the data you want before you garbage it up with listagg (like listagg as the last step for presentation or downstream system requirements). Your other option here is to use the `LIKE` operator `WHERE listagg_column LIKE '%4%' or listagg_column LIKE '%9%'`.

Comment: I agree with the first part, @JNevill, but not with the last as that would match strings that contain e.g. 142 or 990 as well.

Comment: Yes, Actually I want the ones which have both 4 and 9. Wouldn't the or statement include the ones with only 4 and only 9?

Comment: Your request would benefit from showing your query that you want to have changed.

Comment: LISTAGG does not append left and right parentheses, where did those come from? In any case, tell whoever had the LISTAGG idea (tell yourself, if it was yours) that storing data in that format violates the most basic rule of relational table design - something so basic, it is known as the **first** normal form. You should never have to deal with such data (where multiple values appear as a single comma-separated string), and especially if you had to use LISTAGG to put the data in that format in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `HAVING` clause with conditional aggregation:

```
select
  customer_id,
  listagg (something, ', ') within group (order by something) as lst
from mytable
group by customer_id
having max(case when something = 4 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and max(case when something = 9 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
order by customer_id;
```

Another way to write the `HAVING` clause is with `COUNT`:

```
having count(case when something = 4 then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when something = 9 then 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                                                                                                           
If I use the Having clause, I don't really need to use listagg, right?

Comment: @Tanya If you only want the `customer_id` then, no, you do not need to use `LISTAGG`. If you do want to know all the values that you've aggregated then, yes, you do... it depends on what you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

As JNevill commented, you'd rather do it before aggregating the string.

---

Not very pretty, but - see if it helps.

```
SQL> with temp (customer_id, c_listagg) as
  2    -- this is what your query returns
  3    (select 'A', '(4, 6, 8, 9, 10)' from dual union all
  4     select 'B', '(3, 4, 6, 8, 1)'  from dual union all
  5     select 'C', '(1, 2, 4, 6, 9)'  from dual union all
  6     select 'D', '(2, 9, 10)'       from dual
  7    )
  8  -- match 9 (or 4) at the beginning, in the middle and at the end of C_LISTAGG
  9  select customer_id
 10  from temp
 11  where (   c_listagg like '(9,%'
 12         or c_listagg like '%, 9,%'
 13         or c_listagg like '%, 9)')
 14     and (   c_listagg like '(4,%'
 15         or c_listagg like '%, 4,%'
 16         or c_listagg like '%, 4)');

CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
A
C

SQL>
```

Comment: Filtering before aggregation will output different result because it will not show *all* the values for single customer who have both 4 and 9. But if the `listagg` result is not required, this approach will perform better

Answer (score 0):

You can use an easy pattern matching with Oracle [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php) operator. It looks for the match (your number) if it is present inside the *Listagg* column:

- preceeded by either space or open parenthesis `[ (]`
- followed by either comma or closed parenthesis `[,)]`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Listagg, '[ (]4[,)]')
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(Listagg, '[ (]9[,)]')
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1e835db9c0497a1fbfc7c97ea92cca45).

Answer (score 0):

You should do it before aggregation; however, if you have to do it afterwards then:

```sql
SELECT customer_id,
       your_listagg_value
FROM   your_subquery
WHERE  ', ' || your_listagg_value || ', ' LIKE '%, 4, %'
AND    ', ' || your_listagg_value || ', ' LIKE '%, 9, %';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_subquery (Customer_id, your_Listagg_value) AS
SELECT 'A', '4, 6, 8, 9, 10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', '3, 4, 6, 8, 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', '1, 2, 4, 6, 9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', '2, 9, 10' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTOMER_ID | YOUR_LISTAGG_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | 4, 6, 8, 9, 10 |
> | C | 1, 2, 4, 6, 9 |

*Note: if you have the leading and trailing brackets (and your values are numeric) then trim them from the string using `TRANSLATE( your_listagg_value, ',()', ',' )`.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6fa4a38656fbc3171123f0b676a00e04)*